# How do i change the keys to be 0, 1, 2

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP

```
  [227] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 3
        [4] => 1
    )

  [228] => Array
    (
        [7] => 18
        [1] => 33
        [12] => 1
    )
```

how do i change the keys to be in order like this

```
  [227] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 1
    )

  [228] => Array
    (
        [0] => 18
        [1] => 33
        [2] => 1
    )
```

basically resetting the keys

Answer (score 3):

Using [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) will do just what you're looking for:

```
$arr[227] = array_values($arr[227]);
$arr[228] = array_values($arr[228]);
```

Or in a loop:

```
for($i = 0, $count = count($arr); $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $arr[$i] = array_values($arr[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Should be using `foreach` though, instead of a count.

Comment: @Ignacio, `foreach` operates on a copy of the array, not the array itself.  When modifying the array you're iterating, it's usually a better idea to use `for` instead of `foreach`.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: Unless you use reference notation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values).

```
$array = array_map('array_values', $array);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/X6tx8b).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_values()`.

`$a = array_values($a)` will give the array of values of $a, which the keys is beginning from 0.